# Java Spring Boot Rest Api

Tags: java, spring-boot, vuejs2, single-sign-on, siteminder

I am working on a standalone Rest API application using spring boot MVC. I am required to use Vuejs on the front-end to interface with the Java rest service. Another requirement is to secure the UI and rest API with SiteMinder. Being new to vuejs, does anyone have any examples I can use to secure the vuejs app

Comment: Go through this https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-vue-full-stack-crud-maven-application

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Although your question is too generic. Let me try to answer for backend.

- Create **Spring Boot** Project
- Use **Spring Rest API** to communicate between frontend and backend.
- Use **Spring security** to secure your URL based on permission/role.

You may find examples over internet for each task.

Please follow them and in future try to shoot **specific question**.